# MSMQ or MQ Series Round Robin Load Balancing

Tags: load-balancing, msmq, messaging, ibm-mq

I have a scenario where I need to implement a server farm (say 5 servers) which will run 4 instances of a calculation engine:

```
Server 1: E1 E2 E3 E4
Server 2: E1 E2 E3 E4
Server 3: E1 E2 E3 E4
Server 4: E1 E2 E3 E4
Server 5: E1 E2 E3 E4
```

I'd like to utilize a message queue solution whereby each engine is listening on the same queue (eg WORK.QUEUE) for incoming work. In the initial state if work is added then I'd like it to go to Server-1/E1. Then, if more work arrives whilst that instance is busy I'd like it to go to Server-2/E1 and so on. I only want work to go to an E2 instance if all the E1 instances are available.

This sounds to me like a form of round-robin load balancing, but I suspect that this isn't the correct terminology in the message queuing space.

Is this architecture possible using either MSMQ or MQ Series, or does it require some sort of load balancer running on each server to farm out work on a server level?

Answer (score 1):

Round-robin load balancing of messages is certainly a term in the messaging space. In the IBM WebSphere MQ (aka MQSeries) case, it means that each new message will go to a new instance of the queue, i.e

```
Message 1 -> Server-1/E1
Message 2 -> Server-2/E1
Message 3 -> Server-3/E1
Message 4 -> Server-4/E1
```

i.e. it's not based on the busy-ness of the consumer on each server.

Comment: This is true across a cluster but OP said "each engine is listening on the same queue."  It is worth noting that waiting GETter handles are managed in a stack. After processing a message the instance does another GET with wait and its handle is pushed down on the top of the stack.  If messages arrive slow enough the same instance or two will keep getting reused.  This is really efficient for MQ but aggravates the crap of the capacity planning people who see idle capacity. 

(Handle processing description as related in Mark Taylor's MQ Internals session.)

Answer (score 0):

MSMQ just delivers messages. It doesn't care about workload.

The scenario you have described is of multiple readers accessing a single common remote queue. Any load balancing would need to be performed by your own code.

One approach may be to have multiple queues and a simple service that moves a message from WORK.QUEUE to WORK.QUEUE2 if it isn't processed in a set time. All the E1 instances would read messages from WORK.QUEUE, E2 instances from WORK.QUEUE2, E3 from WORK.QUEUE3, and so on. If all the instances at one level were busy, a message would be pushed/cascaded down the queues until it was processed.

Similar to how WCF and MSMQ sub-queues can work.